# VB.Net Dictionaries and Lists with both strings and integers

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to have both a number and a string in a list together in VB.net. From the documentation it appears that you have to set the list as some sort of type before adding to the list.

I am hoping for something akin to python:

```
lst = [1, 2, "a", "b"]
print(lst[1]) >> 2
```

I need to work with both strings and numbers at the same time and having two different lists that I have to iterate through separately, will make this harder to do.

Background: I am working on an application to assist me in creating a very intense DND campaign. Learning this program would be a benefit for my job but since it has to be on my own time I thought a DND campaign would be far more fun to do, lol. There are text for identify different descriptors and dice rolls for generating the numbered value for the states. I am taking the information from the form and performing an INSERT INTO an SQL DB so I can reuse the information instead of rewriting it.

Comment: You can always use `List<object>`.

Comment: Oh thanks I haven't seen that option it looks like you can just do List(Of Values) where values is the object to accept various inputs. Follow up question though since I am new to VB.net, is this an acceptable method or will this cause problems down the road?

Comment: It's usually best to keep things of the same type together: perhaps the numbers should be strings? Or maybe a class with separate members for numbers and strings would be a better fit for the data. If you told us why you need to work with both strings and numbers at the same time, perhaps we could suggest a neater solution.

Comment: I'm with Andrew, you really are best to keep separate types separate.  If you're really after a single list, then create a class with a string and number property, either of which could be empty/null.  Because your goal here is to be saving/querying a DB then I would say you're 100% better off working with the correct types right through the system

Comment: What do you want to do with the numbers?  Do you want to process them numerically, or are they only intended for later info dumps?  If the former, then you would want to handle the types separately.  If the latter, you may want to convert them to strings and have everything as strings.